# Typed Clojure Errors

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I'm implementing [core.typed](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) annotations in my project.  The following code works fine:

```
(require ['clojure.core.typed :as 't])

(t/ann foo [String String -> String])
(defn foo [x y]
  (str x y))

(t/ann works [String String -> String])
(defn works [x y]
  (t/let [z :- (t/Vec String), (shuffle [x y])
          a :- String, (nth z 0)
          b :- String, (nth z 1)]
    (foo a b)))
```

If I alter the function definition slightly, I get a couple different errors:

```
(t/ann fails-1 [String String -> String])
(defn fails-1 [x y]
  (t/let [z :- (t/Vec String), (shuffle [x y])
          ; Fails because (t/Vec String) is not included
          ; in the domain of first or second
          a :- String, (first z)
          b :- String, (second z)]
    (foo a b)))

(t/ann fails-2 [String String -> String])
(defn fails-2 [x y]
  (t/let [[a b] :- (t/Vec String), (shuffle [x y])]
    ; Fails because a and b are of type (t/U nil String)
    (foo a b)))
```

From a type perspective, I would have expected these 3 examples to be more or less equivalent.  Specifically I assumed:

- `(t/Vec String)` would be in the domain of both `nth` and `first`
- The range of `(shuffle [x y])` won't include `nil` when `x` and `y` are of type `String`

Is this a limitation of core.typed, or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to understand here is now `nth` works, and specifically how destructuring uses `nth`.

[nth type](http://crossclj.info/fun/clojure.core/nth.html)

```
(∀ [x y]
   (λ [(∪ (∩ Sequential (Seqable x)) (Indexed x)) AnyInteger → x]
      [(∪ nil (∩ Sequential (Seqable x)) (Indexed x)) AnyInteger y → (∪ x y)]
      [(∪ nil (∩ Sequential (Seqable x)) (Indexed x)) AnyInteger → (∪ nil x)]))
```

Without a default value `nth` will throw an exception if passed a collection and an index outside its bounds. Typed Clojure does not try to prevent this exception.

```
(t/cf (t/fn [a :- (t/ASeq t/Int)] :- t/Int (nth a 0)))
;=> [(t/IFn [(t/ASeq t/Int) -> (t/U Integer Long BigInt BigInteger Short Byte)]) {:then tt, :else ff}]
```

With a default value, the default value is always part of the result type.

```
(t/cf (t/fn [a :- (t/ASeq t/Int)] :- (t/U nil t/Int) (nth a 0 nil)))
=> [(t/IFn [(t/ASeq t/Int) -> (t/U nil Integer Long BigInt BigInteger Short Byte)]) {:then tt, :else ff}]
```

Vector destructuring expands to an `nth` with default of nil.

Also notice that the return type of [shuffle](http://crossclj.info/fun/clojure.core/shuffle.html) has no length information. Sometimes heterogeneous data structures destructure more accurately than their homogeneous counterparts.